# How can one show that $f(x)>2^{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, inequality

Given the function $f: \Bbb N^* \to \Bbb N^*$

$$f(x)=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(2n)$$

How can one show that $f(x) \geqslant 2^{n-1}$?

Here I think I should use induction. Then deduce that $$\frac1{f(1)}+\frac1{f(2)}+...+\frac1{f(n)}\leqslant 2$$

I tried calculating some values like $1$, $2$ and $5$.
I thought using $x^{n-1}$ but I am still stuck.

Comment: Is it right that $F(3)=3*2*3=18$? What trouble do you have with inductive proof? ${F(n+1) \over F(n)} > n+1 \ge 2$.

Comment: @Abstraction I did it right now i have trouble in seconde question

Comment: I can't get what the definition of $f$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For second question, note that ${1 \over F(n)} \le {1 \over 2^{n-1}}$ implies ${1 \over F(1)} + {1 \over F(2)} + ... + {1 \over F(n)} \le {1 \over 2^0} + {1 \over 2^1} + ... + {1 \over 2^{n-1}} < {1 \over 2^0} + {1 \over 2^1} + ... + {1 \over 2^{n-2}} + {1 \over 2^{n-1}} + {1 \over 2^{n-1}} = 2$.

Comment: Ow did you now that its equal to 2

Comment: @user233658 Again, by induction (if you need strict proof). Intuitively, it is ${1 \over 2^0} + ... + {1 \over 2^{n-2}} + ({1 \over 2^{n-1}} + {1 \over 2^{n-1}})$ = ${1 \over 2^0} + ... + ({1 \over 2^{n-2}} + {1 \over 2^{n-2}})$ = ${1 \over 2^0} + ... + {1 \over 2^{n-3}} + {1 \over 2^{n-3}}$ = $...$ = ${1 \over 2^0} + {1 \over 2^0} = 2$.